How to find subgraph with maximum total edge weight
Let G be a undirected graph with weighted edges (The edge weight can be positive or negative). I want to remove some nodes from G, so that the sum of edge weights among remaining nodes is maximum.

Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

It seems to me that branch-and-bound search techniques ought to work well.

Ditto on Brian Tung's comment, but also: if this isn't homework or some textbook exercise, where did you find it and what would be considered a solution? (there are some obvious trivial solutions, but there may also be mathematically interesting solutions that are impractical as well as efficienct solutions)

Search for maximum edge-weighted induced subgraph.

As @RobPratt mentioned this problem has name of maximum edge-weighted induced subgraph (MEWIS) problem.
This problem is NP-hard. Let's reduce the maximum independent set (MIS) problem for a graph $G$ to MEWIS problem for a weighted graph $H$. To build the graph $H$ from the graph $G$ add to it a vertex $u_i$ and an edge $\{\,u_i, v_i\,\}$ of weight $1$ for every vertex $v_i$ of the graph $G$. Every edge of the graph $G$ should get in the graph $H$ weight $-n - 1$. Then all vertices $v_i$ in an optimal solution of MEWIS problem for the graph $H$ are independent. Otherwise total weight would become negative, while $0$ is feasible (a subgraph containing only one vertex $v_1$). And there is no restriction to include all $u_i$'s. At the same time since only pairs $\{\,u_i, v_i\,\}$ may increase the total weight, number of $v_i$'s is maximized in the optimal solution of MEWIS problem. Therefore every optimal solution of MEWIS problem for the graph $H$ corresponds to an optimal solution of MIS problem for the graph $G$. Since this reduction is polynomial, MEWIS problem is NP-hard.
So you may try to find any exponential algorithm based on branch-and-bound or branch-and-cut techniques.
